# Are JavaScript arrays actually linked lists?

Tags: javascript, arrays, linked-list

I'm new to Javascript, and notice that you don't need to specify an array's size and often see people dynamically creating arrays one element at time. This would be a huge performance problem in other languages as you would constantly need to reallocate memory for the array as it increases in size.

Is this not a problem in JavaScript? If so, then is there a list structure available?

Comment: In languages with resizable arrays, the actual memory allocated is typically doubled everytime it has to grow. As a result, you are not going to constantly reallocate memory in any language.

Comment: Thanks guys, that works fine for me. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't committing a javascript faux pas.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It most likely depends on what JavaScript engine you use.

Internet Explorer uses a mix of sparse arrays and dense arrays to make that work. Some of the more gory details are explained here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/04/08/performance-optimization-of-arrays-part-ii.aspx.

Answer (score 29):

Javascript arrays are typically implemented as hashmaps (just like Javascript objects) with one added feature: there is an attribute `length`, which is one higher than the highest positive integer that has been used as a key.  Nothing stops you from *also* using strings, floating-point numbers, even negative numbers as keys.  Nothing except good sense.

Answer (score 12):

The thing about dynamic languages is, well, that they're dynamic. Just like ArrayList in Java, or arrays in Perl, PHP, and Python, an Array in JavaScript will allocate a certain amount of memory and when it gets to be too big, the language automatically appends to the object. Is it as efficient as C++ or even Java? No (C++ can run circles around even the best implementations of JS), but people aren't building Quake in JS (just yet).

It is actually better to think of them as HashMaps with some specialized methods too anyway -- after all, this is valid: `var a = []; a['cat']='meow';`.

Comment: Might depend on your definition of "valid".  It would certainly run on every compliant version of Javascript, it's performant and portable and all those other good CS things.  It's a really bad plan, though.

Comment: And, people have built quake in JS and webGL :P

Comment: Reading your comment and just smiling in 2023 @fabspro

Comment: @IsmoilShokirov things sure have changed on what is now called the 'web platform' :')

Comment: @fabspro I have no idea *WHAT* you're talking about. I just installed a Flash extension in my browser so that I could watch videos on YouTube.

Comment: @fabspro And I only learned about JS Wolfenstein after this post, and that was particularly buggy IIRC. Do you know which projects were running Quake (or Doom) in JS in the early 2010's? I'm mostly curious.

Comment: @cwallenpoole me too - I found this video, a java port of quake was itself ported to the browser using GWT, which is old, but was a combination of a java-to-js compiler and an easy way to interoperate java with javascript code, which would have been used to interface with webgl - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhMN0wlITLk and here is an article https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/04/html5-and-webgl-bring-quake-to-the-browser/

Comment: @cwallenpoole of course, we now have emscripten which has led to things like dosbox, PC emulators, mac emulators, all kinds of C/C++ software being able to run in the browser. Originally it worked by emitting javascript as an LLVM backend, but now i imagine it uses webassembly.

Comment: @fabspro I just learned about that library. You're right: it uses WebAssembly. I seriously wish I had similar for PHP, it would make my current project much easier.

Answer (score 8):

No.

What JavaScript arrays are and aren't is determined by the language specification specifically section [15.4](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4).  `Array` is defined in terms of the operations it provides not implementation details of the memory layout of any particular data structure.

Could `Array` be implemented on top of a linked list?  Yes.  This might make certain operations faster such as `shift` and `unshift` efficient, but `Array` also is frequently accessed by index which is not efficient with linked lists.

It's also possible to get the best of both worlds without linked lists.  Continguous memory data structures, such as [circular queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) have both efficient insertion/removal from the front and efficient random access.

In practice, most interpreters optimize dense arrays by using a data structure based around a resizable or reallocable array similar to a C++ `vector` or Java `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4):

They are actually more like custom objects that use the properties as indexes.
Example:

```
var a = { "1": 1, "2": 2};
a.length = 2;
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    console.log(a[i]);
```

`a` will behave almost like an array, and you can also call functions from the Array.prototype on it.

Comment: Don't you miss the zero index?

Comment: I don't know what @Eliu is trying to show. The code will never work this way (perhaps the intention??). String keys need to be referenced as strings, not as integers. So even ```a[1]``` will not result in a value. The proper code to list the items would be using a ```for .. in``` or using e.g. ```console.log(a[''+(i+1)]);```

Comment: Or maybe defining each key as a number, which is way more simpler? Anyway, even with a syntax mistake, I think @Eliu tried to illustrate the situation - and even using string keys as if they were number ones, IMO the explanation was good enough to understand the main idea.

Comment: @MichielvanderBlonk This is not true at all. Objects can only have strings and symbols as property identifiers. If you use a number to access a property, it will be converted to a string. @Eliu's code here will work as long as you fix the 0-index which is missing from the object `a`. I think what he's trying to show is that Arrays are just normal objects that happen to have numbers as their property keys.

Comment: @LeonardoRaele Yes you are right, and I tried the code, it happens to work, but mostly as a side effect instead of as how it was intended. I think it might confuse the OP even more, even though it's technically correct.
Consider this
```var a = { "1": 1, "3": 3};
a.length = 4;
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    console.log(a[i]);```
You'll see the output for the magic key 2 as 'undefined' because JS has no idea that counting should be involved in the keys. The item with key 2 is simply missing from the list. Using `for..in` would resolve that problem.

Comment: I don't understand your point. What do you mean by side effect? Of course it will print `undefined` for 0 and 2 as these keys doesn't exist in the object in your example.

Comment: so is it O(n) to retrieve a value from an a certain index of an array?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript arrays are not true arrays like in C/C++ or other languages. Therefore, they aren't as efficient, but they are arguably easier to use and do not throw out of bounds exceptions.