# Are array values stored in continuous blocks to in the memory(RAM) in JS?

Tags: javascript

I know array values are properties of the particular array object  but I just wanted to know whether they are stored in continuous blocks of memory or not.

Comment: Yes. Why do you care?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855875/how-are-the-js-arrays-internally-resizing and many others

Comment: @Bergi Why do you say "Yes", when it is implementation dependent.

Comment: What is reason for "downvote" cast for Question?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Because I've never seen an implementation that's silly enough not to do this

Comment: Thanks all guys for helping me

Comment: Respected Bergi I say that success lies in details so I asked even though I respect you thoughts